# How to get Hybrid view of google map  in Android Application

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, android-maps

i can see the difference on Google Maps, but on an Android MapActivity 
I'm struggling to find the difference. 
For 'map' I call: mapView.setSatellite(false); 
For 'satellite' I call: mapView.setSatellite(true); 
But for hybrid view... I tried playing with 
mapView.setStreetView(true); but this doesn't seem to affect anything 
either way. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of posts that will help you implement it:

[Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html)

[Obtaining User Location](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html)

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

create a class that extends Service

```
public class myService extends Service
```

override the

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
```

in your activity

```
if(!myService.isInstanceCreated())
startService(new Intent(youractivityclass.this, myService.class));
```